How to add a custom field in Page layout with api
I'm trying to add a custom field created in Lead Object with help of SOAP API to Page layout called Lead-Lead Layout but I'm not able to do so and getting this error
XML Body :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header>
      <SessionHeader xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
         <sessionId>{access_token}</sessionId>
      </SessionHeader>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <updateMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
         <metadata xsi:type="Layout">
            <fullName>Lead-Lead layout</fullName>
            <layoutSections>
               <layoutSection>
                  <layoutColumns>
                     <layoutColumn>
                              <field>Lead.Lead_leading__c</field>
                     </layoutColumn>
                  </layoutColumns>
               </layoutSection>
            </layoutSections>
         </metadata>
      </updateMetadata>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

Error :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}layoutSection invalid at this location in type LayoutSection</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Anyone any solutions please!

you can use the Salesforce Metadata API to retrieve your page layout first, then edit the xml and push it back into your org.
If you already have Salesforce CLI installed. First connect to the org where you want to make this modification. (Documentation Link)
Then you can retrieve your Layout. Then add your new field, in the XML, as any 'layoutItems'. Save and deploy back this file to your org.
Note this is using the Salesforce Metadata API and not SOAP api.
Credits:
Special thanks to Matt Kaufman from this Stack Overflow post for telling you can't just add fields into a layout, but first retrieve it, then change it, then re-upload it back and of course, to the person who asked the question as well.
